# Open Specific Drive Using Netrw Vim

Tags: vim, netrw

I am using Vim80 on Windows 10. Using Netrw command , by default it will open up my `%HOME%` path. I want to open specific disk drive on my computer like `F:` using netrw. I have searched through similar questions on Stack Overflow and found answers like using `:Ex F:` or `:cd F:\` but it does not change the default directory. What is the netrw vim command that will enable me to change the drive I am working on?

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the wrong thing, Netrw has no default directory, it just opens your active directory. 
So if you open a `cmd` navigate fo `F:` and then run vim, you will have what you want.

But i know that is not the workflow in windows. so you can change the "starting directory" properity on the shortcut to your vim.

```
right click on vim Icon -> property/shortcut/Start in
```

Answer (score 0):

as Doktor OSwaldo stated Netrw doesn't have a default directory. However an alternative approach i've used sometimes is to clone my Vim shortcut by going to the file location:

[image: nav]

Then cloning the shortcut under a new name:
[image]

Then i simply enter the directory (or drive) i want vim to open with netrw by default, like so:

[image: shortcut]

Then i can find vim in the windows menu easily:

[image]

Which allows me to start up my vim instance like this:

[image]

I tend to do this per project which gives me nice project oriented searching available from the windows menu. Anyway, i hope this helps although i understand it was slightly different to what you wanted ideally. If i were you i would create a shortcut per drive so you could search vim and see results like:

- vim
- vim-f-drive
- vim-c-drive
- vim-d-drive